# Shiny - Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make an app with `shiny`, when I run the app with the code below appears an error.

Error:

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..2`.
ℹ Input `..2` is `site == input$cueva`.
x Input `..2` must be of size 672 or 1, not size 0.
  202: <Anonymous>
```

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

sampleTypeVector <- c("Tapete microbiano", "Estromatolito", "Sedimento", "Suelo")
caves <- c("Chimalacatepec", "Iglesia")

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Taxonomic composition"),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(4, " ", 
               pickerInput("sample.type", label = "Sample", 
                           choices = sampleTypeVector,
                           multiple = TRUE,
                           options = pickerOptions(
                               actionsBox = TRUE
                           ))),
        column(8, " ",
              pickerInput("cave", label = "Cave", 
                          choices = caves,
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = pickerOptions(
                              actionsBox = TRUE
                          )))
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(6, " ", label = "Barplot",
               plotOutput("barplot", click = "plot_click"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- reactive({
        phy1 %>%
            filter(sampleType == input$sample.type, site == input$cave)
    })
    
    output$barplot <- renderPlot({
        phylum_barplot(data(), sample, relativeAb, Phylum, colorsVector)#function which makes a barplot with ggpplot
    }) 
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And if I select all the options, my plot appears with fewer bars than it should, like the image below. It should be 48.

[image]

I try to fix the error adding `sum()` as I saw in other examples like this one: [Getting error while using ggplot with r-shiny (Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190867/getting-error-while-using-ggplot-with-r-shiny-warning-error-in-problem-with). But when I add `sum()` in `filter()` appears the next error and my barplot doesn't appear.

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `sum(sampleType == input$tipo.muestra, site == input$cueva)`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a integer.
  202: <Anonymous>
```

And I don't know how to fix it.

My data are here: [data_shiny.csv](https://github.com/Nayeli-Luis/datsets/blob/main/data_shiny.csv)

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hard to tell without the ability to run your app (no data for the choices `sampleTypeVector` or `caveVector`), but try replacing the periods in your object names with underscores. In the translation from R to JS, periods can cause problems.

Comment: Do you have a column named `sampleType` and `site` in your data? Can you provide data to test the code?

Comment: Ready! I already upload my dataset. Thak you for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828079/problem-with-filter-input-1-with-shiny-r/67828428#67828428) similar to yours, and the solution was to use `%in%`instead of `==`in `filter()`. Maybe it solves your problem too.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a masking issue resulting in you calling the wrong filter function.

Try `dplyr::filter(...)` instead of `filter(...)`.

Comment: I change that part of the code and it still not working :C. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and error on a project. I found the problem is that the server code:

> filter(sampleType == input$sample.type, site == input$cave)

is requesting the values from your pickers input$sample.type and input$cave, but on app startup the pickers do not have a value so it is trying to filter on NULL values. That is what the error is telling us at "must be of size 672 or 1, not size 0."

You could fix by setting the picker initial value with the "selected" argument of pickerInput here are the arguments:

> 

```
pickerInput(
  inputId,
  label = NULL,
  choices,
  selected = NULL,
  multiple = FALSE,
  options = list(),
  choicesOpt = NULL,
  width = NULL,
  inline = FALSE
)
```

You second error seems like a data type mismatch for your lookup item "sampleTypeVector".

> Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> ℹ Input `..1` is `sum(sampleType == input$tipo.muestra, site == input$cueva)`.
> x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a integer.
> 202: .