# Problem with `filter()` must be size of x or 1, not size 0 shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I try to create a shiny app. Here i want to use the downloadhandler to create a pdf download. The pdf is created based on the inputs of the user in the ui. They can input a date using dateInput. I am trying to give these dates to the downloadmodule and then to filter them. The data im trying do filter is in an rds file. The data im using is called 'Chargedate' and is in a date format. When trying to filter this data, i get the following error: 'Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 5999 or 1, not size 0'

```r
downloadObjUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  downloadButton(ns("data_download"), label = "Download Data")
}

downloadObj <- function(input, output, session) {
   
  sD <- reactive({input$startdatum})
  eD <- reactive({input$enddatum})

output$data_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "Test"
    },

content = function(file) {
    
 
      pdf(paste0(file))
      rawdat <- readRDS("data.Rds")  

      rawdat<-filter(.data=rawdat,
                     `Chargedate` > sD())


#creation of plots...

      dev.off()
}
)
}
```

Here the ui and server

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

  dateInput("startdatum", "Start:", value = "2023-01-01"),
  dateInput("enddatum", "End:", value = "2023-12-31"),
  downloadObjUI(id = "download1")
  
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  callModule(downloadObj, id = "download1")
  
}
```

People in other post suggested using 'dplyr::filter()'. This resulted in the same error. When i run the filter 'directly', so just writing it into the server function i do not get an error.

```r
server <- function(input, output,session) {

 startdatum <- input$startdatum

observeEvent(input$actionbutton, {

 rawdat <- readRDS("data.Rds")  

      rawdat<-filter(.data=rawdat,
                     `Chargedate` > startdatum)

 })
  
}
```

So the problem occurs when converting the dateInput with the reactive() or somewhere along those lines.

Old Post with similar Problem:
[Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. with shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828079/problem-with-filter-input-1-with-shiny-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)